# Where can I find UniSynEdit to download?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE and I really need this component. I searched the net and I unfortunately didn't find it. Can anyone give me a link to it?

Comment: think I've found it!!
http://www.da-soft.com/download/synedit/unicode-synedit-d2009-d2010-/details.html

Comment: maxwell that version is not updated, check the repository for the most recent updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maxwell this is the site of [synedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/) (and UniSynedit).  if you want the more recent version you must check the [svn repository](http://synedit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synedit/SynEdit/) , because the [SynEdit-2_0_3.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/synedit/) file listed in the site is not updated.